# How do I create a dictionary of functions in PHP?

Tags: php, function-pointers

I want to have a dictionary of functions. With this dictionary, I could have a handler that accepts a function name and an array of arguments, and executes that function, returning the value it returns if it returns anything. The handler would throw an error if the name does not correspond to an existing function.

This would be very simple to implement Javascript:

```
var actions = {
  doSomething: function(){ /* ... */ },
  doAnotherThing: function() { /* ... */ }
};

function runAction (name, args) {
  if(typeof actions[name] !== "function") throw "Unrecognized function.";
  return actions[name].apply(null, args);
}
```

But since functions aren't really first class objects in PHP, I can't figure out how to do this easily. Is there a reasonably simple way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Just interested why do you need this and why not use static class instead?

Comment: "But since functions aren't really first class objects in PHP" Not true. Anonymous functions (which is what your code shows) are regular PHP objects, of class Closure (http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$actions = array(
    'doSomething'     => 'foobar',
    'doAnotherThing'  => array($obj, 'method'),
    'doSomethingElse' => function ($arg) { ... },
    ...
);

if (!is_callable($actions[$name])) {
    throw new Tantrum;
}

echo call_user_func_array($actions[$name], array($param1, $param2));
```

Your dictionary can consist of any of the allowable [`callable`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) types.

Answer (score 3):

I don't clearly get what you mean.
If you need an array of functions just do:

```
$actions = array(
'doSomething'=>function(){},
'doSomething2'=>function(){}
);
```

You can than run a function with `$actions['doSomething']();`

Of course you can have args:

```
$actions = array(
'doSomething'=>function($arg1){}
);


$actions['doSomething']('value1');
```

Comment: I didn't realize that you could do that in PHP

Comment: In PHP you have no limits (IMHO)

Comment: Anonymous functions is new in v.5.3 or so, I believe.

Comment: @deceze: damn you almost copied my answer :P

Answer (score 2):

You could use PHP's [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) for that:

```
class Dictionary {
   static protected $actions = NULL;

   function __call($action, $args)
   {
       if (!isset(self::$actions))
           self::$actions = array(
            'foo'=>function(){ /* ... */ },
            'bar'=>function(){ /* ... */ }
           );

       if (array_key_exists($action, self::$actions))
          return call_user_func_array(self::$actions[$action], $args);
       // throw Exception
   }
}

// Allows for:
$dict = new Dictionary();
$dict->foo(1,2,3);
```

For static invocations, `__callStatic()` can be used (as of PHP5.3).

Comment: You may also use "real" methods and check for their existance with [`method_exists`](http://de.php.net/method_exists). Then you avoid the ugly array structure inside your class.

Comment: Wouldn't this omit `__call()` entirely? Manual says it *"is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context."*

Comment: I didn't try, but if so, you can use a prefix like underscore for the methods. Then call then from outside without underscore and let `__call` then call the internal methods prefixed with underscore.

Answer (score 1):

```
// >= PHP 5.3.0
$arrActions=array(
    "doSomething"=>function(){ /* ... */ },
    "doAnotherThing"=>function(){ /* ... */ }
);
$arrActions["doSomething"]();
// http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php


// < PHP 5.3.0
class Actions{
    private function __construct(){
    }

    public static function doSomething(){
    }

    public static function doAnotherThing(){
    }
}
Actions::doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

If You plan to use this in object context You do not have to create any function/method dictionary.

You can simply raise some error on unexisting method with magic method `__call()`:

```
class MyObject {

    function __call($name, $params) {
        throw new Exception('Calling object method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$name.' that is not implemented');
    }

    function __callStatic($name, $params) { // as of PHP 5.3. <
        throw new Exception('Calling object static method '.__CLASS__.'::'.$name.' that is not implemented');
    }
}
```

Then every other class should extend Your `MyObject` class...

http://php.net/__call

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

`call_user_func` will let you execute your functions from their names as a string and pass them parameters, I don't know the performance implications of doing it this way though.